# Re index pivot table index in sequential order?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

Edit here is a partial view of the data frame

```
     Day        Forecast     Temperatures  City
0   Tonight     Partly Cloudy   46         DC
1   Thursday    Mostly Cloudy   44         DC
2   Tonight     Mostly Sunny    71         Mia
3   Thursday    Partly Sunny    73         Mia
```

I used a pivot table on my data frame and it order it in ascending order.

```
 weather.pivot_table(index=['Day'], values='Temperatures',columns = 'City', aggfunc='mean')
```

Results

```
 City     Mia   DC

 Day        
Friday    72    51
Saturday  74    50
Sunday    67    55
Thursday  73    44
Tonight   71    46
```

How do you re index pivot table index 'Days' in order like (Tonight, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)

```
  City    Mia   DC

 Day
Tonight   71    46  
Thursday  73    44  
Friday    72    51
Saturday  74    50
Sunday    67    55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally by reindexing:

```
df = weather.pivot_table(index=['Day'], ...)
new_index = ['Tonight', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df.reindex(new_index)
```

P.S. I retract my suggestion to drop NaNs. They are here for a reason and should be kept for further processing.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me NAN values. I added the data frame above to show how I changed the data.

Comment: The NaNs represent the days for which there is no data. You can either remove them with `.dropna` (see modified example), or not include them in the new index.

Comment: But if you set dropna()...you will delete all row if just have 1 NaN

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar True, I made a change to the answer.

Comment: or also .fillna('') in the end

Comment: replace .dropna(how='all') by .fillna('')

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar `.fillna` is wrong because once you fill NaNs with 0's, you cannot tell anymore which 0 is a placeholder and which is an actual 0. Better leave it NaNs.

Comment: I said .fillna('')  not .fillna(0)

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar This is even worse because all your numbers become strings. Just leave the NaNs, they have their own purpose.

Comment: No , because if you use .dropna(how='all') you will drop rows if you add more data in your dataframe

Comment: @excelater take care in what case use dropna

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, I'm adding more data in case you have that scenery:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = """
Day,Forecast,Temperatures,City
Tonight,Partly Cloudy,46,DC
Thursday, Mostly Cloudy,44,DC
Tonight,Mostly Sunny,71,Mia
Thursday,Partly Sunny,73,Mia
Friday,Partly Sunny,12,Mia
Friday,Partly Sunny,12,CA
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')
print(df.pivot_table(index=['Day'], values='Temperatures',columns = 'City', aggfunc='mean').reindex(['Tonight', 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']).fillna(0))
```

result:

```
City       CA  DC Mia
Day                  
Tonight        46  71
Monday               
Tuesday              
Wednesday            
Thursday       44  73
Friday     12      12
```

Comment: You understand that after imputing empty strings your data is not numeric anymore? Try `x.mean()` or `x.sum()` or any other arithmetic operation.

Comment: Just replace ' ' by 0 in fillna()

Comment: I already told you what is the problem with imputing 0: they may be indistinguishable from real data. You should learn the purpose of NaNs.